# How can I change the ActionBar color after AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my app I'm performing an `AsyncTask` in `onPageFinished` attached to the WebView. This method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView myWebView, String url)
{
    new SendRequestAsyncTask().execute();

    // when a page has finished loading dismiss any progress dialog
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And `SendRequestAsyncTask` looks like this:

```
public class SendRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        //runs in ui thread
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myscript.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "12345"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // writing response to log
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {

                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);

                String[] parts = responseStr.split(":");
                parts[1] = parts[1].replace("\"", "");
                parts[1] = parts[1].replace("}", "");

                if (parts[1].equals("01")){
                    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "No success: " + parts[1]);
                }

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //runs in ui thread you can update the layout here
    }
}
```

However, this crashes my app. So my guess is that I'll need to change the Actionbar's color in the `onPageFinished` method. However, I don't really know how to get the variable from the `AsyncTask` to `onPageFinished`. Furthermore, I don't know how to change the color into a color from `@color/` xml file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
    public class SendRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    //runs in ui thread
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String strReturn = "";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myscript.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "12345"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // writing response to log
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);

            String[] parts = responseStr.split(":");
            parts[1] = parts[1].replace("\"", "");
            parts[1] = parts[1].replace("}", "");

            strReturn = parts[1];
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    return strReturn;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //runs in ui thread you can update the layout here

    if (result.equals("01")){
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "No success: " + parts[1]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to set the color in onPostExecute.  That's on the UI thread and can safely touch the UI.  Just move the call there and you should stop crashing.  You may need to pass some data to onPostExecute to do so correctly, of course (or store it in class variables of AsyncTask).

Comment: Makes sense indeed, how can I pass data to onPostExecute correctly?

Comment: The value returned from doInBackground is passed into onPostExecute.